# Is it safe to eval $BASH_COMMAND?

Tags: bash

I am working on a shell script that constructs a complex command from variables,  e.g. like this (with a [technique that I've learned from the Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time)):

```
#!/bin/bash

SOME_ARG="abc"
ANOTHER_ARG="def"

some_complex_command \
  ${SOME_ARG:+--do-something "$SOME_ARG"} \
  ${ANOTHER_ARG:+--with "$ANOTHER_ARG"}
```

This script dynamically adds the parameters `--do-something "$SOME_ARG"` and `--with "$ANOTHER_ARG"` to `some_complex_command` if these variables are defined. So far this is working fine.

But now I also want to be able to print or log the command when I'm running it, for example when my script is run in a debug mode. So when my script runs `some_complex_command --do-something abc --with def`, I also want to have this command inside a variable so I can e.g. log it to the syslog.

The Bash FAQ demonstrates a technique to [use the `DEBUG` trap and the `$BASH_COMMAND` variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I_want_a_log_of_my_script.27s_actions) (for example for debugging purposes) for this purpose. I've tried that with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG="test string"

trap 'COMMAND="$BASH_COMMAND"; trap - DEBUG' DEBUG
echo "$ARG"

echo "Command was: ${COMMAND}"
```

This works, but it doesn't expand the variables in the command:

```
host ~ # ./test.sh
test string
Command was: echo "$ARG"
```

I guess I have to use eval to expand `echo "$ARG"` to `echo test string` (at least I haven't found a way without `eval` yet). The following does work:

```
eval echo "Command was: ${COMMAND}"
```

It produces the following output:

```
host ~ # ./test.sh
test string
Command was: echo "$ARG"
Command was: echo test string
```

But I'm not really certain if I can use `eval` safely like this. I've unsuccessfully tried to exploit some things:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG="test string; touch /x"
DANGER='$(touch /y; cat /etc/shadow)'

trap 'COMMAND="$BASH_COMMAND"; trap - DEBUG' DEBUG
echo "$ARG" $DANGER

echo "Command was: ${COMMAND}"
eval echo "Command was: ${COMMAND}"
```

It seems to handle this well, but I'm curious if someone else sees an issue that I've missed.

Comment: This is what I've been using for years in a sudo wrapper,  I have never noticed an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility is to make a wrapper function that will at the same time print the command and execute it, as follows:

```
debug() {
    # This function prints (to stdout) its arguments and executes them
    local args=() idx=0 IFS=' ' c
    for c; do printf -v args[idx++] '%q' "$c"; done
    printf "%s\n" "${args[*]}"
    # Execute!
    "$@"
}
```

So that in your script you can do:

```
debug echo "$ARG"
```

No need to fiddle with the trap. The drawback is that it adds some `debug` keywords all over your code (but that should be fine, it's common to have such stuff, like asserts, etc.).

You can even add a global variable `DEBUG` and modify the `debug` function like so:

```
debug() {
    # This function prints (to stdout) its arguments if DEBUG is non-null
    # and executes them
    if [[ $DEBUG ]]; then
        local args=() idx=0 IFS=' ' c
        for c; do printf -v args[idx++] '%q' "$c"; done
        printf "%s\n" "${args[*]}"
    fi
    # Execute!
    "$@"
}
```

Then you can call your script as:

```
$ DEBUG=yes ./myscript
```

or

```
$ DEBUG= ./myscript
```

or just

```
$ ./myscript
```

depending whether you want to have the debug info or not.

I capitalized the `DEBUG` variable because it should be treated as an environment variable. `DEBUG` is a trivial and common name, so this might clash with other commands. Maybe call it `GNIOURF_DEBUG` or `MARTIN_VON_WITTICH_DEBUG` or `UNICORN_DEBUG` if you like unicorns (and then you probably like ponies too).

**Note.** In the `debug` function, I carefully formatted each argument with `printf '%q'` so that the output will be correctly escaped and quoted so as to be reusable verbatim with a direct copy and paste. It will also show you exactly what the shell saw as you'll be able to figure out each argument (in case of spaces or other funny symbols). This function also uses direct assignment with the `-v` switch of `printf` so as to avoid unnecessary subshells.

Comment: The function works great, but unfortunately my command contains redirections and the "excute in background" control operator `&`. I had to move those to the function to get it to work - not very nice, but I don't think there's a better way. But no more `eval`, so I've got that going for me, which is nice :)

Answer (score 5):

`eval "$BASH_COMMAND"` runs the command.

`printf '%s\n' "$BASH_COMMAND"` prints the exact specified command, plus a newline.

If the command contains variables (i.e. if it's something like `cat "$foo"`), then printing out the command prints out the variable text. It is impossible to print the variable's value without executing the command — think of commands like `variable=$(some_function) other_variable=$variable`.

The simplest way to get a trace from executing a shell script is to set the `xtrace` shell option by running the script as `bash -x /path/to/script` or invoking `set -x` inside the shell. The trace is printed to standard error.

Comment: I know about `xtrace`, but that doesn't give me very much control. I tried "set -x; ...; set +x", but: 1) the "set +x" command to disable xtrace is printed too 2) I can't prefix the output e.g. with a timestamp 3) I can't log it to syslog.

Comment: "It is impossible to print the variable's value without executing the command" - good example, I hadn't considered such a case. It would be nice though if bash had an additional variable next to `BASH_COMMAND` that contains the expanded command, because at some point it has to do variable expansion on the command anyway when it's executing it :)